# G1 marking identification SOT 23 3

Tags: identification

Wonder if someone can help identify this component.

I am certain it is SOT 23-3 after matching another component next to it. I Could be wrong. I think it may be a shunt regulator or something.

The 3V supplied to the pin comes from an LM2931A that provides 5V however there is a voltage divider in between to get 3V. 430 ohms and 680 ohms to ground to get 3 volts.

The 1.99V is the voltage sense and is calculated through another voltage divider from 67.2V. 33680 ohms and 1K to ground to give us 1.99V. The 1.99V Voltage sense goes into Pin 22 ADC7 of an Atmega 8A (32pin) as various input voltages can be used outside of the chip itself. Marked as G1, not C1. I am guessing this component might be an over voltage protection reading up to 2V or it will connect to GND. Cant be an NPN as it is a voltage sense that the atmega needs to know.

Does anyone know what this is?

[image]

Comment: the surroundings on that board might be important, as much as showing a "reverse engineered" schematic. However, "G1" stands a good chance of not naming any specific component, so maybe you'll just go by what it does.

Comment: All my searches give me that the part could be an NPN transistor, but the marked voltage levels say that it can't be. Could you please check the terminals with a DMM in diode mode while the circuit is not energized?